# Azure Automation Runbook fails to complete with no error

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I'm attempting to run a backup of an API Management service. I can do this in PS from my local machine without issue using the code below under my sub owner login context.

When I attempt to run it as a runbook, I only get back:

```
Suspended
The runbook job was attempted 3 times, but it failed each time.  Common reasons that runbook jobs fail can be found here:  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-troubleshooting-automation-errors
```

There are no errors, only the above.

I've tried to run under user and system assigned identity, without any difference in outcome.

```
    $method="UA"
    $apiManagementName="xxxx-Prod";
    $apiManagementResourceGroup="xxxx-Prod";
    $storageAccountName=xxxxstorage";
    $storageResourceGroup="xxxations";
    $containerName="xxxxbackups";
    $blobName="prodnpapim.apimbackup"
    $date = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd")
    $outputBlobName = "$($date)$($blobName)"
    
    $identityName = "xxxx-OPS-MID";
    $identityResourceGroup = "xxxxtions";
    
try
{
    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Connect-AzAccount -Identity
}
catch {
    Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
    throw $_.Exception
}

$storageKey = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $storageResourceGroup -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName)[0].Value

$storageContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageKey

"Starting backup"

try{
    Backup-AzApiManagement -ResourceGroupName $apiManagementResourceGroup -Name $apiManagementName `
        -StorageContext $storageContext -TargetContainerName $containerName -TargetBlobName $outputBlobName
}
catch{
    "Backup-AzApiManagement error"   
    exit
}
```

Without any errors, I'm stuck - given it works fine in local PS.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I 'fixed' the problem.

I had to perform the following steps.

Import the modules I needed.

```
Import-Module Az.Accounts
Import-Module Az.ApiManagement
Import-Module Az.Storage
```

Disable Context Save

```
Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process
```

Set Context

```
$AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity).context

$AzureContext = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $AzureContext.Subscription -DefaultProfile $AzureContext
```

This is using system-managed identity

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an opening `"` where you define `storageAccountName`

```
$storageAccountName=xxxxstorage"
```

Not sure if that's a syntax error pasting to SO or if that would be the same within your actual runbook.

If it fails after that still then you would have to use more Write-Output statements and verbose logging in your runbook job to identify where the problem is between each step.

Comment: that was an error with the copy-paste / anonymizing of data

Comment: Then I would consider looking at the constraints here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-disaster-recovery-backup-restore?tabs=powershell#constraints and if you have storage account firewall enabled then you will have to add APIM. You can enable verbose logging which may give you more insight on the cmdlet functionality or lack thereof. VerbosePreference may need to be amended and `Backup-AzApiManagement` have the `-Verbose` flag appended.